# Redirecting output stream to SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, sax

A third party method outputs XML to terminal. How can I redirect it to a stream readable by SAX parser? I am trying something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
System.setOut(ps);
client.response(); //prints to terminal
System.out.flush();
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

... define handler ...

saxParser.parse(baos,handler);
```

However, since the last line does not work, I was hoping for something like this:

```
InputStream xmlInput = new InputStream(baos);
saxParser.parse(xmlInput,handler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream xmlInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask a follow-up meta-question? How one does arrive at an answer to a question like mine (other than googling it, which I tried)? I am a newbie using intelliJ. Is there perhaps some way to use intelliJ smart features to figure it out?

Comment: @AdamSikora personally in the same situation I figured out that since there was such a thing as ByteArrayOutputString, there would probably be such a thing as ByteArrayInputStream. So I explored the javadoc around ByteArrayOutputString and found what I needed. For the initial guess that there is such a thing as ByteArrayOutputStream, you'd need to Google/ask around how to have a OutputStream write to memory, or if you're like me suspect that such a thing would exist, and explore around java.io.\* and all known implementations of OutputStream.